# Android Facebook Permission Issue

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to follow the Android Facebook Tutorial here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/ - however when I try it out on a phone, it is not bringing up the permission box, it is simply redirecting to the phones browser and going to the main facebook page.

I tried adding permissions via:

```
facebook.authorize(myclass.this, new String[] {"user_photos"}, new DialogListener() {
```

I am not getting any form of error back from the facebook api either... is there some form of setting I need to change on facebook in order for it to not redirect to the main web site?

I have tried searching around on here but I cant seem to find anyone else having problems with it redirecting to the browser on the phone ... or not getting an error back.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding     android:launchMode="singleInstance" to your Activity inside the manifest?

Comment: no luck with that one - still getting the same result unfortunately.

Comment: I followed this guide: http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2011/02/28/30-minute-guide-integrating-facebook-android-application/